# Behavior of fstream as a bool and fstream.good() function

Tags: c++, while-loop, ifstream

I recently used fstream for a homework assignment and I was wondering about how two things worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("fileone.txt");
    int myInt = 0;

    while (myFile.good()) { // What is the difference between myFile and myFile.good()?
        if (!myFile.eof()){
            myFile >> myInt;
            cout << myInt << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a snippet of my actual code I am working on. In another post, someone said that if I used `while(myFile)` , it would automatically convert into a bool. What is the difference between using this and using the member function `.good()` of the `ifstream` class? I know that `.good()` breaks out of the while loop when I reach the end of the text file but how does using the stream name behave?

Comment: They act close enough to the same that *neither* should be used to control a loop with the intent of reading to the end of the file. You want to check the result of the actual read operation, so for the loop above you want `while (myfile >> myInt) cout << myInt << "\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOStream classes have 4 functions for assessing the *stream state*: `good()`, `bad()`, `fail()`, and `eof()`. Excluding `good()`, each function checks a single bit in the underlying stream state and returns whether or not the bit is on (are there errors?). `good()` in particular checks if *all* the bits are off (is the stream valid?). These are what they are for:

- `good()`: The stream has not encountered an error.
- `bad()`:  The stream has encountered an error that effects the integrity of the stream (i.e memory allocation failure, no buffer, etc.)
- `fail()`: Typically a recoverable error (formatting/parsing failure).
- `eof()`: The end-of-file (`EOF`) character has been reached.

When performing I/O, it is integral that you check for errors in the stream while processing input. What novices typically don't know is that the *only* function that was meant to be used to check for valid input is `fail()`. All the other functions are useful in other cases but not for conditioning input.

Futhermore, novices also fail to realize that input must be performed *before* checking for  errors. Doing otherwise allows an unchecked extraction, allowing the body of the loop to access the value that was not produced from a valid extraction.

Streams have a boolean operator that returns `!fail()`, this allows you to check the stream in an elegant way *after* performing input, like this:

```
while (myFile >> myInt) {
    // ...
}
```

This is the best way to perform input. The extraction itself should be present within a conditional context so that the body of whatever its being used in is executed only if the extraction succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

The `bool` conversion is defined so that the following are the same:

```
if (stream) { ... }
if (!stream.fail()) { ... }
```

There is a difference between `stream.good()` and `!stream.fail()`: `!fail` is also `true` the end of file.

And one more big issue with your code: you should check if the read is successful before using the input. So this is really bad:

```
        myFile >> myInt;
        cout << myInt << endl
```

because you have not checked if you really succeeded to read an `int` into `myInt`.

**TLDR:**

Use this for reading `int`s from a file:

```
while (myFile >> myInt) {
   cout << myInt << endl;
}
```

Reason: `myFile >> myInt` returns `myFile` so it will invoke the `bool` conversion which should be used as the loop condition.